# How to give the total of the price and the quantity at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First of all, please excuse my JS script knowledge. It's very little and mainly I'm a PHP programmer. I've found this great and simple script which calculates the total of the products table rows and also gives the grand total of the whole table. However, it only does the calculation when I change the quantity. Is it possible to make it does the calculation every time I change the price OR the quantity?
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         
        $(function () {
            $('.subtot, .grdtot').prop('readonly', true);
            var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");

            $tblrows.each(function (index) {
                var $tblrow = $(this);

                $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', function () {

                    var qty     = $tblrow.find("[data-name=qty]").val();
                    var price   = $tblrow.find("[data-name=price]").val();
                    var subTotal= parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

                    if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                        $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
                        var grandTotal = {total};

                        $(".subtot").each(function () {
                            var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                        });

                        $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes, but nothing you show makes this run anytime so how do you run this

Comment: Why is this tagged with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.subtot, .grdtot').prop('readonly', true);
        var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");

        $tblrows.each(function (index) {
            var $tblrow = $(this);

            function updatePrice() { // Move to separate function
                var qty     = $tblrow.find("[data-name=qty]").val();
                var price   = $tblrow.find("[data-name=price]").val();
                var subTotal= parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

                if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                    $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
                    var grandTotal = {total};

                    $(".subtot").each(function () {
                        var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                        grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                    });

                    $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
                }
            }

            $tblrow.find('.price').on('change', updatePrice); // watch for price change
            $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', updatePrice);   // watch for qty change
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear Shadab it worked perfectly. You made my day friend :)))

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? You can trigger an event using '.qty, .price' in the table.

And I recommend using constants like `const qty = ...` instead of global variable `var qty= ...` inside of a block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.subtot, .grdtot').prop('readonly', true);

        $("#tblProducts").on('change', '.qty, .price', function () {
            const $tblrow = $(this).closest('tr');

            const qty     = $tblrow.find("[data-name=qty]").val();
            const price   = $tblrow.find("[data-name=price]").val();
            const subTotal= parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

            if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {
                $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));

                let grandTotal = 0;
                $(".subtot").each(function () {
                    const stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                    grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                });
                $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```